# Error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, servlets, classnotfoundexception

```
import org.openl.rules.runtime.RulesEngineFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
// Action rule
public static String ActionRule(ClassRule classRule, String gender,
        String marialStatus) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // define the interface
    RulesEngineFactory<?> rulesFactory = new RulesEngineFactory<Object>("D:/GreetingCustomer.xlsx");
    Object rules = rulesFactory.newInstance();
    Class<?> clazz = rulesFactory.getInterfaceClass();

    // define params
    String Gender = gender;
    String MarialStatus = marialStatus;

    // define info of rule method

    int iNumOfParams = classRule.getListItem().size();
    // define param types
    Class[] paramClases = new Class[iNumOfParams];
    paramClases[0] = String.class;
    paramClases[1] = String.class;

    // set param value
    Object[] params = new Object[iNumOfParams];
    params[0] = Gender;
    params[1] = MarialStatus;

    String result = "";
    try {
        Method method = clazz.getMethod(classRule.getRuleName(),
                paramClases);
        System.out.println("* Executing OpenL rules...\n");
        // invoke method
        Object interestAmount = method.invoke(rules, params);
        if (interestAmount != null) {
            System.out.println("Siri Say: " + interestAmount);
            result = interestAmount.toString();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong input value");
            result = "Wrong input value";
        }
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    }
    return result;
}
```

When i call the ActionRule method Eclipse give me error messages:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azh5H.png)

I added org.openl.rules-5.16.2.jar into Libraies but it still dont work. I dont know why? What anyone have solution to solve this problem ? 
Thanks so much.

Comment: Post the exception stack trace, as code-formatted text, in your question. And please respect the Java naming conventions, and don't ignore exceptions.

Comment: Your server does not have the class org.openl.rules.runtime.RulesEngineFactory (in a jar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not eclipse that's missing the library, it's tomcat. Make sure your deployment has `org.openl.rules-5.16.2.jar` placed into `WEB-INF/lib` of your webapp.

Afterwards, restart tomcat or redeploy your app

Comment: yeah! i added org.openl.rules-5.16.2.jar into WEB-INF/lib and it's worked. Thanks so much

Comment: Yes. I accepted the answer. Sorry about forget it :D